# Espresso command line multiple packages not working

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, android-espresso

It works perfectly fine for 1 package:

```
❯ adb shell 'am instrument -w -e package com.myapp.package1 com.myapp.test/com.myapp.MyTestRunner'

com.myapp.package1.ClassXTest:.......

Time: 22.288

OK (7 tests)

❯ adb shell 'am instrument -w -e package com.myapp.package2 com.myapp.test/com.myapp.MyTestRunner'

com.myapp.package2.ClassYTest:.....

Time: 6.959

OK (5 tests)
```

However, it detects 0 test when I use multiple packages; therefore, skipping running all the tests!

```
❯ adb shell 'am instrument -w -e package com.myapp.package1,com.myapp.package2 com.myapp.test/com.myapp.MyTestRunner'


Time: 0

OK (0 tests)
```

What's happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has acknowledged this as a bug and it should have been fixed by now: https://issuetracker.google.com/u/1/issues/111567467